# reactjs timepicker breaking site error occurred in the <ForwardRef(KeyboardDateInput)> component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to add a timepicker to my formik framework - but when I've tried adding the component. Its an older react project mostly using class components - is it because its being rendered in a class component?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker';

export default function CommonlyUsedComponents() {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <TimePicker />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

I get this error "react-dom.development.js:20085 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(KeyboardDateInput)> component

[image]

```
"KeyboardDateInput.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: renderInput is not a function
    at KeyboardDateInput (KeyboardDateInput.js:32:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:17044:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19098:1)"
```

```
react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:117 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onChange` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(TimePicker)`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this - I had to add a renderInput textfield. I've been able to use the timepicker for just time handling with momentjs filtering it as HH:mm:ss

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//text
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment';


import dayjs, { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/TimePicker';

//date
import moment from 'moment';

class TimeInputField extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
      return (
            <>
              <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                <TimePicker 
                  value={dayjs(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'T'+this.props.field.value)}
                  onChange={(value) => {
                    this.props.form.setFieldValue(this.props.name, moment(value.$d).format('HH:mm:ss'));
                    this.props.onHandle(this.props.name, moment(value.$d).format('HH:mm:ss'));
                  }}
                  renderInput={(params) => {
                    return (<TextField {...params} name={this.props.name} />)
                  }}
                />
              </LocalizationProvider>
            </>
      )
    }
}

export default TimeInputField
```